# Example of noetherian ring that nilradical is prime and (0) is not primary

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, noetherian

> I have problems to give an example of noetherian ring $R$ whose nilradical is prime and $(0)$ is not primary.

I can find a lot of examples when $(0)$ is not primary, for example $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2,xy), \mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy)$ etc. But problems arise in nilradical. I know that nilradical is prime iff spectrum of this ring is irreducible, but I don't know if it could help. I would like any hint.

Comment: The nilradical of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2,xy)$ *is* prime. It is $(x)/(x^2,xy)$.

Comment: I thought earilier about it, but my calculations has shown that it isn't prime. I had mistake, you're right, I checked it again.